# How to build a single project within a solution?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project within a solution that has a lot of other projects.  I'd like to build a single project.  The project doesn't have any dependencies on other projects in the solution.  When I right click and build this project, all projects get built.

Is there a way just to build the one project?

Comment: that's weird, try unloading all other projects

Comment: Are you sure you are building the project and not the solutions. Verify the project dependencies,  Right Click the project -> Build Dependencies -> Project dependencies and Build order.

Answer (score 0):

Try right click->Project only->Build.

Comment: There isn't a "Project only" option.